# Add a user to a group in ezpublish

Tags: ezpublish

I want to add a user to a group in addition to his existing groups.

```
$user = eZUser::fetchByEmail('myemail.com');
$user->attribute('groups'); // array(2,4)
```

Now i want to add this user to group 5 with existing groups.
So

```
$user->attribute('groups');
```

will become array(2,4,5)

Answer (score 1):

`eZUser` is the DAO for a system user, and you don't have to manipulate it. What you want is adding a location to a user content so that it's in multiple groups.

To avoid manipulating the core API, I'll suggest that you use this :

```php
$operationResult = 
    eZOperationHandler::execute( 'content',
                                 'addlocation',
                                 array( 'node_id' => $nodeID,
                                        'object_id' => $objectID,
                                        'select_node_id_array' => $selectedNodeIDArray ),
                                 null,
                                 true );
```

With :

- `$nodeID` being the content node_id related to your user
- `$objectID` being the content object_id related to your user
- `$selectedNodeIDArray` bein an array of targets node_id (the futur parent locations of your user content)